# why am I getting a null value on return of this?

Tags: apex, email

**UPDATE**

Big thanks to everyone who chipped in to help me out!

pulling my hair out. Anyone spot the issue? Am I going nuts or is it just because its at the end of the day?

```
public id User {get;set;}
public User ActiveUser {get;set;}
// public string UserName {get;set;}
// public string useremail {get;set;}
// public string useremail {get;set;}
String userEmail;
String userWWID;


public void getUserName(){
    String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();

    User activeUsers  = [SELECT Email, WWID__c FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()]; //Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()
    List<User> Users = [SELECT Id, WWID__c FROM User WHERE Id=:userinfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
    String userWWID = Users[0].Name;
}

public PageReference PageRedirect() {
    string host = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('host');
    string url = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();
    String ParentId = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('parameter');
    PageReference PageRedirect = new PageReference('https://webbsite/Home.do' + userWWID);
    PageRedirect.setRedirect(true);
    return PageRedirect;
}
```

Comment: userEmail is seems to be part of your constructor?

Comment: As a side note, you might want to consider using a different name for the local page reference variable. Calling it `Redirect` in a method called `Redirect` doesn't make for the most readable code :)

Comment: The core problem here that both solutions are trying to address is that a `string + null == null`. Check that `userEmail` has a value before you concatenate it to the other string.

Comment: Put System.debug(...) under each initialization or assignment and you will find the issue. May the force be with you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as written uses `UserWWID` in the redirect, which is set in `GetUserId()`, but that method is never called.  If it were called, you'd get an error on the last line of `GetUserId()`, since you are trying to reference the Name field, which wasn't included in your query.  Here's a simplified version of your code which I think will work, but I'm making the assumption that the field you need in your constructed URL is actually User.WWID__c.

```
// just store a reference to the user, then use
// activeUser.name, activeUser.id, activeUser.wwid__c, etc.
// as needed in code or VF
public User activeUser {get;set;}

// Constructor: name should match your class name
public ControllerName(){
    User activeUser  = [ SELECT id, Name, Email, WWID__c 
                           FROM User 
                          WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
}

public PageReference PageRedirect() {
    system.debug(activeUser);
    if (activeUser.wwid__c == null) {
        return null;
    }
    string targetUrl = 'https://webbsite/Home.do/' + activeUser.wwid__c;
    return new PageReference(targetUrl);
}
```

A few notes:

- As @CasparHarmer noted in his answer, you should move your setup into a constructor method, so it always runs when your controller is created.  Constructors have no return type, and the name must match your class name, so change `ControllerName` in the sample code above.
- I'm assigning a query result directly to an sObject (activeUser).  This is nearly always bad, since a query returning 0 or >1 records will throw an error, however, querying `user where id = :currentUserId` is always safe in a controller, since there's always a user.  Just be sure the user has FLS on the WWID__c field, or it will come back null.   Since activeUser is a public property, you can stick `{!activeUser.wwid__c}` in your VF page temporarily for debugging, to make sure your are getting a `wwid__c` value.
- Check the targetUrl line.  Your code didn't have `/` or a `?param=` at the end of the URL; I'm guessing you need one or the other.
- I omitted the `setRedirect()`; per [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm?search_text=pagereference) it isn't needed when the URL refers to an external website.

**Update:**  I've updated the PageRedirect() method, so that if User.WWID__c is null, the method returns null.  Since you are calling this as an `action` on your VF Page, if the method returns null, it doesn't redirect, and just outputs the VF Page.  Along with this change, add something to your VF page to show what happened, since it will only be shown if the redirect fails.  For example:

```
<apex:page controller=...>
    User WWID__c:  {!user.wwid__c}
</apex:page>
```

Also added a debug statement to output the user data.

Comment: Jason,

Thanks a bunch for such an in depth comment, it really helped! One last question though, what do you mean by FLS on the field? I implemented your recommended solution, and it seems to be working but I'm getting a null reference error now, so that's probably what you were talking about!

Comment: Would it matter that the VF page is constructed like this?

<apex:page showHeader="false" showChat="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="RedirectTestPageClass" action="{!Redirect}">

Should it be an extension instead?

Comment: FLS = 'Field Level Security' - does the running user have permission to see the field?  And no, you don't need to use an extension in this case.

Comment: Yeah I'm running it as myself, as an admin. When I look at the logs it looks like it runs the query 

15:43:34.0 (25239429)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[12]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, Name, Email, WWID__c FROM User LIMIT 1
15:43:34.0 (45389119)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[12]|Rows:1

but then below when it gets to the redirect portion, it gives out a ugly null pointer

Comment: I added the updated method above and it still attempts to redirect. The debugs I added trigger correctly, and the code stops at the pagereference statment. 

Looking through the logs, it seems its grabbing the correct data from the User.` VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[12]|activeUser|{"s":1,"v":{"Id":"0054B000000UZNuQAO","Name":"CustomerLogin Site G (9 more)`

So i am unsure why it's attempting to both redirect me and says its null. Interestingly enough, when I take off the redirect action and just have the page on there, its completely blank even with a <apex:outputField value="{!activeUser.wwid__c}"/>

Comment: Well, the debug statement cut off, but it looks like the running user is a Customer Community Guest user, which may not have permission to read WWID__c.  Check FLS on that field for the public profile (Setup->Sites->site->Public Access Settings).  If you are testing a public community page, it runs as the guest user, not your user account.  Try changing the debug statement to show activeuser.wwid__c==null; maybe add another to output activeuser.

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out. I went ahead and filtered the query so that its now pointing to a specific user Id WHERE id ='0054B000000RKOhQAO'. I know this user has permissions to view the field. For some strange reason It's still giving me that null pointer error. It looks like it finishes the constructor fine but then for whatever reason the variable in the redirect throws it bonkers. At this point I've taken out the WWID__c field and i'm just trying to ammend the ID field as I know everyone can see that

Comment: Double check the `targetUrl` line again... I just noticed (and fixed) a typo in my original answer that had an extra 'new' in there.  Not sure if that would even compile, but worth checking to see.  Should read `string targetUrl = 'https://webbsite/Home.do/' + activeUser.wwid__c;`

Comment: It's totally that, I think we both just found the issue at the same time! I removed the + 'Id' field and i was still getting an error on the pagerefence! 

It works now! Much appreciated my friend.

Answer (score 1):

What's it look like to me is variable conflicts ( Global vs local).

You are defining "userEmail" local variable value somewhere in your code.

```
 User activeUsers  = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
 String userEmail = activeUsers.Email;
```

And later using the same named global variable in your Redirect method.

Just change your code snippet to:

```
User activeUsers  = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
userEmail = activeUsers.Email;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah i added this initially to see if it helped, and it didn't. Not sure why. I changed my code to look for another value, and I still got null

Answer (score 1):

I can't see all your code, but from what I can see, you have defined the initial userEmail a local variable, not a class-level one.

Make the string `userEmail` a member variable.

Eg

```
class YourClassName {
    String userEmail;

    //constructor
    public YourClassName (){
        User activeUsers  = [SELECT Email FROM User WHERE Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()];
        userEmail = activeUsers.Email;
    }
    //now you can use the userEmail variable anywhere.
```

Comment: Hey guys,

first thanks a bunch for answering! Unfortunately, for some reason none of the answers above helped, I'm still getting a redirect of the website with null, so basically www.websiteexacmple.comnull 

Not quit sure whats going on, in the logs it seems that my query is not returning any results?

Comment: Actually I take that back now, I've changed it for the time being to just ]SELECT Email FROM User limit 1], so I'm getting a return value now. Its still pulling up null on my redirect.

Comment: Ok, to fix this, you are going to need to put all the relevant code up - how and were you define the variable and how you trigger the redirect.

Comment: I added the entire code above

Comment: So I updated the code to run a query of 

[SELECT Id, WWID__c FROM User WHERE id ='0054B000000UDOW']

It's returning a value, but not appending the value to the redirect..its still getting null. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate form:

Turn your `getUser()` method into something that returns a `User`; getters that have side effects can be problematic. Getter only makes one soql call per transaction but can be referred to via `this.u` many times throughout code.

Make your constructor as simple as possible - in this case, `{}`.

```
private User u() {
    get{
        if (this.u == null) 
            this.u = [select id, email, wwid__c, name from User where id = :UserInfo.getUserId];
        return this.u;
    }
    private set;    
}

public PageReference PageRedirect() {
  string host = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('host');
  string url = ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl();
  String ParentId =   System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('parameter');
  PageReference pg = new PageReference('https://webbsite/Home.do/' + this.u.wwid__c);
  pg.setRedirect(true);
  return pg;
}
```